# Verification in Selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, verification

I am new to the automation world, I am trying to verfy an item in the list to see if it has been deleted or not.. I have used the following syntax but it says company found, which is not suppose to be the answer.. Please help

```
internal void verifycompany()

{

        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        int b = 1;
        bool CompanyName = Driver.driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='companies']/tr[" + b + "]/td[1]")).Displayed;
        if (CompanyName == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("company not found, test succesful");
            Base.test.Log(LogStatus.Info, "company not found, test succesful");
        }
        else
        {
            b++;
            Base.test.Log(LogStatus.Info, "Company found, test unscuccesful");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could you share relevant HTML as well??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, isDisplayed does not return false if it is not displayed, it throws an exception stating that it couldn't be found (geez thanks).

What I did is create a reusable method where I can pass in an element and it'll throw it through a try catch and return true if found, or false if the exception is thrown.

Something like the below - I use java but it should help you figure out a way around your problem:

```
public boolean isDisplayed(WebElement webElement) {
    try {
        return element.isDisplayed();
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

If you don't want to create a reusable method, just throw your find element line into a try catch.

```
boolean CompanyName;

try {
    CompanyName = findElementAndIsDisplayedCode;
} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    CompanyName = false;
}
```